# translated into, to, in X?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

Are these all valid? I find it confusing that there are so many ways to say this.

> I translated the text into English.
>
> I translated the text in English.
>
> I translated the text to English.

Are these all interchangeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only correct ones are **into** or **to**, and [**into** is far more common than anything else](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=translated%20%2A%20english&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ctranslated%20%2A%20english%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btranslated%20into%20english%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btranslated%20in%20english%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btranslated%20from%20english%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btranslated%20to%20english%3B%2Cc0).

Think of the translation as being like motion - in fact, [the word *translate* itself comes from the Latin meaning "to carry over".](https://www.etymonline.com/word/translate)  You are not just "within" English, but *carrying the work into English from somewhere else*, much like the difference between being *in* a room and walking *into* a room.  This is why we say "I write *in* English" (English was the language where the writing occurred) but "I translated it *into* English." (the translation carried the work from another language).

Comment: Ill note that "I translated the text in English" sounds either like the text was in english, or I used english to translate, neither of which sound very natural.